# SQL to have one specific record at the top, all others below

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to put together a query that will display one specific record (found by the record's primary ID) at the top, and display all other records below it, sorted by date (I have "date_added" as one of the fields in the table, in addition to primary ID).

I could do this with a UNION (first select would locate the record I want, and the other select would display all other records), but I'm wondering if is there perhaps a better way?

I'm using Oracle, by the way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this by sorting by two fields

The first would be an expression that returns 0 if the row is the one you want or 1 if it isn't. Sort will be ascending so you get your preferred record first.

The second sort field would be date_added so the remaining records are sorted in this order.

Afraid I don't know oracle by in sql server it would be something like

```
select * 
from the_table 
order by (case id when 999 then 0 else 1 end), date_added desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
What does "order by 0" mean, by the way? I've noticed that I cannot use this by itself, e.g. only "ORDER BY 0". (I get the error: "ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression")

Comment: `ORDER BY <number>` has a special meaning in Oracle, it will sort on the nth column.  Of course there's never a 0th column.  With the CASE, it will add a new column to every row and sort on that.  The new column will be 1 for the matching primary key, and 0 everywhere else.

Answer (score 8):

An easier way would be a fancy order by construct.  Here's an example for pk = 123:

```
select *
from YourTable
order by case when yourpk = 123 then 1 else 2 end, date_added
```

Comment: this would put the specific record to the end, should be "... then 1 else 2 end ..."

Comment: @ammoQ: Thanks, answer edited (reko_t posted the same idea earlier tho)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Oracle exactly, but you could perhaps do something like..

```
ORDER BY IF(id == THE_ID, 0, 1), date_added
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't support IIF, but you can `DECODE(id,THE_ID,0,1)` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can sort more than one record to the top using the same technique

999 first
998 second
followed by everything else sorted by date

select *

```
from the_table 
order by (case id when 999 then 0 when 998 then 1 else 2 end), date_added desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `Table`
ORDER BY (`id` = THE_ID) DESC, `date_added` DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple way would be to recognise that you want to display two separate things and therefore write to separate straightforward queries. One query to retrieve the first record, and the second to retrieve the sorted list. There is no real performance advantage to doing anything more than this because of one unique record.

Comment: Yes, but there are advantages to doing it as a single SQL statement. Some environments (e.g. reporting suites) do not allow easy reuse of SQL constructs, so he might have to repeat most of the SQL twice, which is problematic for maintenance. Also, doing it in SQL is more consise :-).